# Finding MAX even and odd values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find the MAX even and odd values of a given array.
In this case I need the console to print that the max even is 8 and the max odd is 11
This is revised from another question because of the cool down time for asking questions

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question03 {

    public static int[] array;//The array to be used in the problem
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;//Used for the stairs
        if(args == null || args.length == 0)
        {

            int[] tempArray ={2,4,6,8,11};//You may change these values to test 
            array = tempArray;
        }
        else
        {

        }

        //Write your solution here
        int evenMax = array[0];
        int oddMax = array[0];
        for (int x =1; x<array.length; x++){
            if(evenMax %2 == 0)
            {
                 if (evenMax<array[x])
                 {
                   
                 }
          }
          if(oddMax<array[x]){
            oddMax=array[x];
          }
        }

        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + evenMax + ". The smallest number is: " +oddMax);
```

Comment: Please take a look in Stackoverflow rules. When a person answer your question you should accept that if it solve your problem. Besides, you can't completely change your question after someone already answered that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Streams from Java 8 along with Optional:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3};
    Arrays
        .stream(array)
        .filter(n -> n > 0)
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
}
```

vide: [DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--) and [OptionalDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html)

Comment: You need to filter out negative values.

Comment: Is ignoring negatives now

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing your code, I added a variable to store the number of elements that should be used as divisor when calculating the average value. In this case `total` store the sum of all elements in the array.

```
int elements = array.length;
double total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] < 0)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    if(array[i] == 0)
    {
        elements--;
    }
    total += array[i];
}
double average = total / elements;

System.out.println("the average was " +average);
```

P.S. As any algorithm there are many ways to solve this problem. But, here, my intent was to help you according to your line of thought.

Comment: @WillColumbia you're welcome! If you consider this question solve your problem please upvote and mark as accepted. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > 0)
        {
            total += array[i];
            ++count;
        }
    }
    double average = total / count;
    System.out.println("the average was " +average);
```

Or even:

```
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(double value: array)
    {
        if(value > 0)
        {
            total += value;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    double average = total / count;
    System.out.println("the average was " +average);
```